# HTML5 input type=number should allow only unsigned integer

Tags: javascript

How to prevent other number related characters other than **unsigned integer**

For example `-` `e` `.`..etc

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrEGrK

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="#" class="container">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input class="form-control" onkeyup="value=isNaN(parseFloat(value))?1000:value" type="number" value="0">
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain what you want to achieve, and add some code example in the question. Not just a link, please.

Comment: @Mario Alexandro Santini I need to type salary in this field. that means user shouldn't be able to type dot, comma, minus....etc

Comment: In addition to all the answers, don't forget to validate the format on the backend. You don't want your service to crash and be potentially exploitable.

Comment: @JoseGómez There is backend validation. it is just `UX` purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function validate(e) {
  var ev = e || window.event;
  var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    ev.returnValue = false;
    if(ev.preventDefault) ev.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're ok with HTML5 why not use the pattern attribute and define a number only regex?

```
<input pattern="[1-9][0-9]*" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a clue from your implementation, what if you use a regular expression like that:

```
onkeyup="value=/^\d+$/.test(value)?value:1000"
```